# Haar measure from Cartan metric?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, haar-measure

Consider the following $d$-dimensional Lie algebra, $$[X_i, X_j] = f_{ij}^k X_k$$ so that the Cartan metric is given by $$g_{ij} = f_{ia}^bf_{jb}^a$$ Now, what I wish to know is whether the Cartan metric is literally the metric over the Lie group (which I understand is also a smooth manifold) ? Also, does the measure $$\int \sqrt{g}~ d^d \sigma$$ (where $\sigma^i$ parametrizes the lie group) qualify as a haar measure of the lie group?

Comment: Yes, it is a metric, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097374/cartan-killing-metric-and-lie-groups).

Comment: @DietrichBurde But is it related to the haar measure?

Comment: From a metric you define a volume form. A (left- or right-) invariant volume form is the Haar measure, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin From what I understand from the discussion on page 206, 207 of (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/gt.pdf), the volume form is defined through the canonical metric. I just want to know whether the Cartan metric will work as well.

Comment: I believe this is what most of us call the Killing form. Note that only when the Lie algebra is semisimple will the Killing form be nondegenerate (and certainly not necessarily positive definite). In the worst case scenario, if the Lie algebra is abelian, then it is identically 0. But when the Killing form is definite, it will give you a (left- or right-) invariant metric on the Lie group, so then you should be fine.